# Package CVXR: Error in as.vector(data): no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Tags: r, optimization, r-s4, convex-optimization, cvx

I am trying to use the package CVXR to do my optimization. I am following the instructions from this page: https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/11/27/introduction-to-cvxr/

My problem is a little complicated to I want to put my coefficient variables (the variables I want to optimize) into a matrix to help with coding. However, I could not do it in R

```
beta = Variable(n)
matrixbeta = matrix(beta,nrow=2)

Error in as.vector(data) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Really appreciate any help.

Comment: `beta` does not contain any data, it's the wrong sort of object to feed to `matrix`. The idea of that package is you do some optimisation, get an object `answer` and then you can put the coefficients of that answer into a `matrix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beta` is a S4 object, not a numeric value, so it cannot be placed in a `matrix`. What are you trying to do with the coefficient? You can create an arbitrary `m` by `n` variable with `Variable(rows = m, cols = n)` and use it in mathematical operations as you would a `matrix`.